# Is anyone aware of any HTML5 based language editor with content assist?

Tags: language-agnostic, html, content-assist

Does anyone know of a project that will allow the editing of a language (any language) within a web-page itself (via HTML-5) with content assist (ctrl+space)?

**CLARIFICATION**

I'm not looking for a HTML5 editor (I'm aware of many), I'm looking for a language editor written in HTML5/Javascript that runs within a browser.

Comment: What is a language editor? Like a tool to manipulate Context-Free Grammars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bespin](https://mozillalabs.com/blog/2009/02/introducing-bespin/) is an experimental web-based IDE written by the Mozilla team which can be used to edit HTML and JS (and presumably any other kind of) files.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can get HTML5 Intellisense for Visual Studio [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d).

Comment: Hi, sorry that my question was ambigious, I updated the question to clarify. I'm not looking for a HTML5 editor, I'm looking for a language editor written using client-side HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe DreamWeaver CS5 has the content assist (in Javascript and HTML) for HTML5 Canvas and probably other elements in HTML5 specification

Comment: Check the clarification note, your answer seems not to match because DreamWeaver does not run as an editor in HTML5.